# Break in g:if / g:each

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have loop in gsp like this:

```
<g:each in="${personInstance.followed}" var="c" >
            <g:if test="${c.equals(person)}">
            <g:link id="${person.id}" action="unfollow" controller="message">unfollow</g:link>
            </g:if>
</g:each>
```

How can I use break in g:each or g:if?
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no concept of a `break` in the logical tags of `g:if` or `g:each`. What are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear from the code you posted.

Comment: I need to break this loop when if return true first time.

Comment: So, you have a collection of `persons` in the `personInstance.followed` property and you need to display something if that collection contains the `person`? Is that right? If so there is a much better way do to this (which I can explain in an answer).

Comment: i need to display sth if person is in this collection, and something other if is not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are looking to display one thing or another based on if an instance is within a collection. Your best bet is to use `contains` on the collection. For example:

```
<g:if test="${personInstance.followed.contains(person)}">
  Display your unfollow stuff here ...
</g:if>
<g:else>
  Display your follow stuff here ...
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Groovy and in GSP you don't need `break` and what you really want is to use the `findAll` tag which filters on a condition so your logic would become (untested example code):

```
<g:findAll in="${personInstance.followed}" expr="c.equals(person)" var="c" >
        <g:link id="${person.id}" action="unfollow" controller="message">unfollow</g:link>
</g:findAll>
```